# Document Summary/Preview In-Line In Document Library View

Tags: document-library, list-view, view

I have a requirement to show a summary text from within Word/PDF/Email documents that are stored in a Document Library in-line within the Document Library View.

I can see something similar in the Search results but would like to use this in a Document Library hover if possible.

Is it possible to display a short summary or preview in this way on documents in a library view?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a view with one column (name/title) and add:

```
<style>
/* DOCUMENT PREVIEW */
.js-frame-wrapper { min-height: 650px !important }
.js-callout-content { width: 1100px !important; min-height: 800px !important; }
.js-callout-content { max-width: 1200px !important }
.js-callout-noscroll { min-height: 700px !important }
.js-callout-mainElement { max-width: 1100px !important }
.js-callout-sharedWithInfo { display: none !important; }
.js-callout-sharedWithList{ display: none !important; }
.js-frame-wrapper iframe { style: "" !important; }
iframe[role="presentation"] { width: 1060px !important; height: 840px !important; }


/*magnifier*/
.ms-ellipsis-icon {
top: -141px;
left: -107px;
}

.ms-ellipsis-a {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
}

.ms-list-TitleLink {
    width: 337px;
}

/* DOCUMENT PREVIEW */
```